# scrolling the screen

Tags: iphone

i am a beginner for iphone and xcode pls anybody give me code to make scroll the screen ...

Comment: Scroll it where? Scroll it how? What part needs scrolling? How far do you need it to scroll? Your question is vague.

Comment: Voted to close for "asking how to program". Read the documentation, learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a registered iPhone developer, then you should look at various Sample Code projects. There are probably a couple that deal with scrolling.